# One to One relationship mongoose in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I want to create one to one relation between collections in MongoDB using mongoose ([@nestjs/mongoose and mongoose](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)) and nestjs.
I have a collection of "owners" and "stores" where each "owner" can only have one "store"

*owner.schema.ts*

```
@Schema()
export class Owner {

  /* some schema */

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Store'
  })
  store: Store;
}
```

*store.schema.ts*

```
@Schema()
export default Store {

  /* some schema */

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Owner',
    required: true,
  })
  owner: Owner;
}
```

With the schema above, why can I still add more than one "stores" to the "owners" collection?

*store.service.ts*

```
async createStore(createStoreDto: CreateStoreDto, user: ReqUser) {
    // create store entity
    const entity = {
      ...createStoreDto,
      owner: user.id,
    }
    const store = await this.storeModel.create(entity);
    const saved = await store.save()

    // save store._id to owner.store
    await this.ownerModel.updateOne({ email: user.email }, { store: saved._id })

    return saved;
  }
```

Comment: Can you also include the code where you add another store to a "Owner" document? From my point of view it should not be possible, since you only have a single property "store" in your Owner schema. It would only be possible if you have an array, where you push `ObjectIds` to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that MongoDB is not throwing an error in your case? `$push` is used to push new values to an array. Since your property is defined as an ObjectId, it should not be possible to "push" values to it. Nevertheless your problem should be solved if you just update your document as following:

```
await this.ownerModel.updateOne({ email: user.email }, { store: saved._id })
```

**How to enforce 1-1-relationship in mongoose:**
If you want to establish a One-to-One relation in Mongoose I suggest you to follow these steps (in order to avoid duplicate data):

- decide on the schema that should be the "owner" of the relationship
- define the property that should hold the ref in this schema
- define a unique index on this property so that other documents are not able to also relate to the same foreign document
- (optiona) define a virtual in the other schema, so that the relationship can be queried for from both sides.

Comment: Ok I see, I have changed my schema to "one to many", and I'll change it back so that it related to the previous case.

Comment: still wanna know how MongoDB works with one-to-one relationships.